# Access Alter Table "Allow Zero Length"

Tags: ms-access

I'm working with an old Access database (yes, it's very ugly and I hate it).  I need to modify some of the columns from a VB app that I'm creating.  I have most the modifications setup correctly, but I'm fighting with the fact that modifying a column to text has it default to "Allow Zero Length" to false.

SO 
ALTER TABLE [Applicant Table] ALTER COLUMN [Applicant ID] Text(255)

I need that alter to have "Allow Zero Length" set to true.

I have tried
ALTER TABLE [Applicant Table] ALTER COLUMN [Applicant ID] Text(255) NULL

but that doesn't seem to work either.  I've looked all over for the solution, but can't seem to find a straight answer.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ryan.

---

Thanks for the info.  I'm glad that it's Access and not me.

I guess I'm just going to hack my way through this application since the entire data model is trash anyway.

Comment: What happens when you try it in the GUI (Table Design)?

Comment: Allen Browne, MVP : "Just out of curisioty, why would you want this property set to Yes? For
compatibility with other software perhaps? For a really odd field? In
general, I would consider this a poor idea because:
1) Users can't tell the difference, and
2) Access can't tell the difference. (Try with DLookup())." -- http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/allow-zero-length-using-sql-t1636536.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option isn't available with Jet sql.  You can do it in the Access gui or with vba code.  Example:

```
Public Function setAllowZeroLenStr()    
    On Error GoTo Proc_Err

    Dim db As Database
    Dim tbl As TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tbl = db.TableDefs![Applicant Table]
    Set fld = tbl.Fields![Applicant ID]
    fld.AllowZeroLength = True

Proc_Exit:    
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Exit Function

Proc_Err:    
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Resume Proc_Exit    
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

I concur: there is no ACE/Jet syntax for this setting. If you think about it, the SQL DLL tends to be the Standard 'portable' stuff, things that can be achieved on most SQL products. Most SQLs don't have an explicit (Dis)AllowZeroLength feature so it hasn't made it into the Standard hence not in the ACE/Jet syntax.

FWIW the 'portable' solution, which works for ACE/Jet too, is to use a CHECK constraint e.g. something like:

```
ALTER TABLE [Applicant Table] ADD
   CONSTRAINT Applicant_ID__not_zero_length 
      CHECK (LEN([Applicant ID]) > 0);
```

Allowing a zero length value would require not creating the CHECK constraint in the first place (!!) or `DROP`ing it if it already existed... but why would you want to allow an identifier ("Applicant ID") to be zero length anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

Ages ago I wanted to do the same and ISTR that it simply wasn't possible from DDL/SQL - but you can do it from VBA by locating the field (table.fields) and setting AllowZeroLength to the required value

Answer (score 0):

Use Interop.ACCDBLIB

Try this:

```
    DBLib dbLib = new DBLib();
    dbLib.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    dbLib.Initialize(); 
    dbLib.ModifyTextFieledSetAllowZeroLength(ref TableName, ref FiledName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SetUpTempDbExample()
' Set up a temp database for running report data into.
' Temp DB is killed and re-created on demand (saves having to compact and repair in primary DB).
' Temp table can be relinked to primary DB for further querying
Dim dbTemp As Database
Dim tblTemp As TableDef
Dim idxTemp As Index, idxTemp2 As Index
Const cTempPath = "C:\temp\"
Const cTempDB = "TempReportData"

    '  Delete old temp database (if db is in use, Kill will fail. Resume gracefully.)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Dir(cTempPath & cTempDB) <> "" Then Kill (cTempPath & cTempDB)

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    ' Create a new temp DB.
    Set dbTemp = CreateDatabase(cTempPath & cTempDB, dbLangGeneral)

    Set tblTemp = dbTemp.CreateTableDef("TEMP_SAMPLES")
    
    With tblTemp
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("SAMPLE_ID", dbDouble)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("SITE_ID", dbText, 38)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("SAMPLE_DATE_TIME", dbDate)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("METHOD", dbText, 20)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("MATRIX", dbText, 20)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("COMMENT", dbText, 255)
        .Fields![COMMENT].AllowZeroLength = True
        Set idxTemp = .CreateIndex("SAMPLE_ID")
        idxTemp.Fields.Append .CreateField("SAMPLE_ID")
        idxTemp.Primary = True
        Set idxTemp2 = .CreateIndex("SITE_ID")
        idxTemp2.Fields.Append .CreateField("SITE_ID")
    End With
    dbTemp.TableDefs.Append tblTemp
    tblTemp.Indexes.Append idxTemp
    tblTemp.Indexes.Append idxTemp2

    Set tblTemp = Nothing
    Set idxTemp = Nothing
    Set dbTemp = Nothing

ExitSub:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")"
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```